# Understanding the mechanism used by SDWebImage when used in a UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, lazy-loading, sdwebimage

This question is for my understanding as my code is working fine.
I have looked inside SDWebImage, but it's fairly large and I can't pinpoint how the mechanism I'm questioning works.

OK, let's say I have a tableview full of UIImageViews (one inside each cell), and I call the SDWebImage Category/Extension on each of them to go and lazy load an image from the web.

What mechanism is employed to update the cell as it's on screen with the newly downloaded image, without reloading the tableview?

I ask this as I was surprised to see that when using SDWebImage Extension each of my cells' imageViews image popped into existence as soon as it's corresponding image had downloaded.

I was under the impression that I'd have to reload the tableView, but instead each cells imageView 'automagically' updated when the image was available!

How does this work? Does SDWebImage keep a reference to each cell/imageView it's working with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SDWebImage` inserts the loaded image into the `UIImageView` instance on which the load has been queried.

With `UITableViewCell` you have to be a bit tricky to avoid non-relevant images in your cells, here is why:

1. Imagine you requested the image for `URL` of the first item (`firstURL`) on the topmost visible cell.
2. You scroll down your table, and following happens:

   - the former topmost cell gets reused and appears on the bottom of the table.
   - the image is queried for `URL` of the last cell (`lastURL`).
3. `firstURL` loading completed, and corresponding image is inserted into the image view of the last cell, because it was the image view for which `firstURL` loading has been queried.
4. `lastURL` loading completed, and corresponding image is inserted into the image view of the last cell.

Steps 3 and 4 might look like fast blink in the image view.

To avoid that, you need to address the cancellation of the previous download in `prepareForReuse` method implementation of the `UITableViewCell` subclass.

e.g.

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    [self.imageView sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad];
    self.imageView.image = <placeholder image>;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring UIImageview in UITableviewCell then you can check that SDWebImage is one kind of UIImageView class, so no need to describe which image view refers for downloaded image, as its self identify

Let me show you once..
as we request for image inside cell like this.

```
[cell.imgBrand sd_setImageWithURL:url completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

When first line executed, it will call method inside `UIImageView+WebCache.h` class.
as you can see that class itself UIImageView

```
@implementation UIImageView (WebCache)
```

[Class For SDWebCache UIImageView](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIImageView%2BWebCache.m)